# Save tensor as image doesn't work

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have the following problem:
I have the Tensor `Tensor("content_vgg/conv1_1/Relu:0", shape=(1, 224, 224, 64), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)`

and I want to save it as an image, but whatever I try to do I get an `InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1,224,224,3]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[1,224,224,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]` error

This is my code, I already tried to add the placeholder but even that doesn't work

```
    self.conv1_1 = self.conv_layer(bgr, "conv1_1")
    print(self.conv1_1)
    x = tf.placeholder_with_default(input=self.conv1_1,shape=[1,224,224,64], name='x')

    images = tf.reshape(tf.cast(x, tf.uint8), [224, 224, 64])
    images_encode = tf.image.encode_jpeg(images)
    fname = tf.constant('test.jpeg')
    fwrite = tf.write_file(fname, images_encode)

    self.sess.run(fwrite)`
```

Can someone help me or give me an advice or let me knwo how I can save the Tensor as image with another solution?

Comment: maybe  `bgr` needs a `placeholder` with shape `[1, 224, 224, 3]`, the input image for computing `self.conv1_1`. Plus, not sure `encode_jpeg` can receive a tensor with channels more than 3.

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: The error you got clearly indicates that you didn't give a value for this placeholder, or you gave a wrong shape or wrong data type. maybe you can check on this.